# How can I generate scaladocs for a bazel project in a manner that allows for external dependencies to be used as parameters/return types?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bazel, scaladoc

I am working with a Scala project that is being built using Bazel.  I would like to generate Scaladocs for this project as part of our deployment process.  I am able to generate the docs using the scaladoc command, but I receive a large amount of errors since it is unable to pull in dependencies, such as Apache Spark.

Various functions in my project return or accept DataFrames, and the generated docs simply say that the return type is of Type .

How can I have these dependencies included when I am generating my scaladocs?

I have tried using the `doc-external-doc` command, but have been unable to make it work, but this might be due to me simply misunderstanding the man page for the command. I tried looking for a Bazel rule to generate the scaladocs, but also came up empty handed.